# ¿Cómo puedo listar solo una tabla de un INNER JOIN de sql server sin tener que llamar las otras tablas?

Tags: sql

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es listar de un INNER JOIN de tres tablas solo una pero de manera masiva sin tener que llamar campo por campo es decir...

Esta es mi consulta

```
SELECT *
FROM talonario.fechas_encabezado t1
INNER JOIN talonario.fechas_detalle t2 ON t2.rowid_encabezado=t1.rowid
INNER JOIN talonario.fechas_activacion t3 ON t3.rowid=t2.rowid_fechas_activacion
WHERE t1.fecha='2021-01-06'
```

Lo que quiero hacer es más o menos así

```
   SELECT t1
   FROM talonario.fechas_encabezado t1
    INNER JOIN talonario.fechas_detalle t2 ON t2.rowid_encabezado=t1.rowid
    INNER JOIN talonario.fechas_activacion t3 ON t3.rowid=t2.rowid_fechas_activacion
    WHERE t1.fecha='2021-01-06'
```

Cómo podría listar solo una tabla, me podrían ayudar...

Comment: Es importante mencionar que se desaconseja utilizar el asterisco en el código final y en su lugar se recomienda especificar las columnas necesarias. Esto es para prevenir cambios de comportamiento si varia la estructura de las tablas y reducir tráfico de la red con información innecesaria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que ya agregaste alias a tus tablas, nada más te faltó agregar `.*` a tu consulta esperada.

Por lo tanto, si quieres consultar todos los datos solamente de `t1`, lo que buscas es:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM talonario.fechas_encabezado t1
INNER JOIN talonario.fechas_detalle t2 ON t2.rowid_encabezado=t1.rowid
INNER JOIN talonario.fechas_activacion t3 ON t3.rowid=t2.rowid_fechas_activacion
WHERE t1.fecha='2021-01-06'
```